# How to make {{ compiler('c') }} work, in meta.yaml for conda build, under Windows 10?

Tags: jinja2, conda, recipe, conda-build

I'm trying to use the new `{{ compiler('c') }}` Jinja command in the `requirements:build` section of one of my `meta.yaml` files for `conda build`, under Windows 10.
However, when I do, the build breaks, unable to "find" `cl.exe`, which is strange, because it does find my *Visual Studio* installation (i.e. - I see the correct VS version number reported in the log.).
I'm able to get a successful build, using `vs2019_win-64` instead, but that leaves me w/ a non-portable `meta.yaml` file. :(

Does anyone know what I need to do, to get this working?

*As per @merv 's request:*

`conda-build` version:

```
(base)
$ conda-build --version
conda-build 3.20.5
```

One package I'm attempting to build, which exhibits the behavior described above, is: `Chaco`.
Here are the contents of my `meta.yaml` file for my `Chaco` build:

```yaml
{% set name = "chaco" %}
{% set version = "5.0.0.1" %}

package:
  name: "{{ name|lower }}"
  version: "{{ version }}"

source:
  # path: ../../chaco/
  git_url: https://github.com/enthought/chaco.git
  git_rev: 5.0.0

build:
  number: 1
  script: "{{ PYTHON }} -m pip install . --no-deps --ignore-installed -vv "

requirements:
  build:
    - setuptools
    # - vs2019_win-64        # Uncomment for Windows build only.
    # - {{compiler('c')}}    # Would like to get one of these working, instead of above hack.
    # - {{compiler('cxx')}}
    - git
    - cmake
  
  host:
    - python
    - enable =5.2.1.1
    - Cython
    - importlib_resources

  run:
    # - python
    - enable =5.2.1.1
    # - cython
    - importlib_resources

test:
  # Python imports
  imports:
    - chaco
    - chaco.api
    # - chaco.contour
    # - chaco.downsample
    # - chaco.downsample.tests
    # - chaco.layers
    # - chaco.overlays
    # - chaco.plugin
    # - chaco.scales
    # - chaco.scales.tests
    # - chaco.shell
    # - chaco.tests
    # - chaco.tools
    # - chaco.tools.tests
    # - chaco.tools.toolbars
    - chaco.ui

  # commands:
    # You can put test commands to be run here.  Use this to test that the
    # entry points work.


  # You can also put a file called run_test.py in the recipe that will be run
  # at test time.

  # requires:
    # Put any additional test requirements here.  For example
    # - nose

about:
  home: http://docs.enthought.com/chaco
  license: BSD License
  summary: 'interactive 2-dimensional plotting'
  license_family: BSD

# See
# http://docs.continuum.io/conda/build.html for
# more information about meta.yaml

extra:
  recipe-maintainers:
    - capn-freako
```

Comment: This needs more details. What kind of package is being built? How is compiler used (e.g., in a `build.bat` file)? Maybe share parts of meta.yaml, if possible. Include conda-build version.

Comment: @merv Thanks for your reply! I've added the information you requested to the original question. However, I don't know what you mean by, "How is compiler used?"